# Animation - irregular working of MouseListener

Tags: java, animation, refresh, mouselistener

In my animation one of elements is moving oval. There are two ways to control it. The first is setting x,y position by mouse listener and the second is Key Listener. During first using animation both methods work. But after using stop (clear) button mouse listener doesn't work, but Key method is still working.

Code stop method:

```
 void clear() {
        waves.clear();
        xz_list.clear();
        yz_list.clear();
        time_list.clear();
        f_list.clear();
        time=0;
        timer.stop();
        repaint();
    }
```

MouseListener method:

```
void SourcePosition(double v, String d) {       
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {       
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
                {
                    x_o = e.getX();
                    y_o = e.getY(); 
                    repaint();        

                }                   
            }                     
        });
    }
```

Generally this is application showing Doppler Effect. Start button make setting data from interface, disable interface and start animation and chart. Stop button uses clear() method and enable interface.

Comment: A runnable would example would be more useful

Comment: I've got application with interface.  timer.ActionListener is responsible for animation. Send it? I think that problem is with restarting animation by button. I edited my post adding code of start/stop method.